# Playing a custom sound

Tags: objective-c, iphone

I want to develop an application for iPhone that plays mp3 files. Which framework and functions should I work with?

Thanks in advance,

Sagifw

Answer (score 1):

AudioToolbox. You can check Apple's documentation.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/codinghowtos/AudioAndVideo/index.html#PLAYBACK-PLAY_SOUND_FILES_OF_ARBITRARY_LENGTH

Answer (score 1):

You can't use audio toolbox.

It only plays uncompressed formats.

Use AVAudioPlayer instead.